# Craft 2: possible to control plugin triggering order?

Tags: plugin-development, craft2

I have a Craft site which has 2 different plugins listening to the same event (the Contact Form beforeSend event).

The outcome is one is being triggered before the other and this is causing issues. Is there any way of specifying the priority of one plugin over the other or ensuring that they happen in a specific sequence?

Cole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, nothing I'm aware of for Craft 2, I'm afraid.

In Craft 3, there's still not a great solution, but there is a `$append` parameter where you can kind of force it to go to the top of the list: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Event.php#L103

But that would stop a plugin that was loaded after yours to use the same parameter and come out on top.

Comment: okay, thanks Brad. "issue" with Snaptcha where my plugin was being called first so Snaptcha was rejecting the submission but after my code which partially defeated the purpose. think have managed a fix by calling the Snaptcha service validate method directly from my own plugin. cheers!